# How to display a PHP result in a jQuery dialog box

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a PHP contact form that currently takes you to a separate page. I would like the "successful/error message" to appear in a jQuery dialog box instead of re-directing you to another page. Or if I could get it to target a DIV and could then display it when submitted I just need something to show the results on the same page other than iframe.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "info@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "Message From Testing.com";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.    ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['message'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you     submitted.');       

}



$name = $_POST['name']; // required

$email = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$message = $_POST['message']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($message) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->
<html>

<div id="dialog" title="Thank You">
<p>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</p>
</div>

</html>

<?php

}

?>
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<form name="contactform" method="get" autocomplete="on">
                    <input type="text" class="contact-form-        input" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="text" class="contact-form-input" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <input type="text" class="contact-form-input" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone">
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="contact-form-textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <input type="button" class="form-submit-button" name="send" onclick="mail();"  value="Send">
                    <input type="reset" class="form-submit-button" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML and the Jquery ? The php file is not necessary

Comment: @Netzach I literally just finished typing a comment asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this after submission of the form, you have to do it before submission of the form. Add an onClick event to your form pointing to a function with an AJAX request. Then display the popup on success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mail() {
    var email = jQuery("#email").val();
    var name = jQuery("#name").val();
    var telephone = jQuery("#telephone").val();
    var message = jQuery("#message").val();
    var postData = { email: email, name: name, telephone: telephone, message: message };
    jQuery.post('mail.php',
        postData,
        function ( jsonResults ) {
            jQuery("#dialog").show();
        },
        'text'
    );
}
</script>

<form id="mail-form" method="get">
    ...
    <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="mail();" />
</form>
```

Comment: I posted my HTML, I used the Jquery you posted and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you move your dialog box to the same page as your HTML and then hide it?

Comment: I placed the script that you posted to my HTML file. No did not hide the dialog box.

Comment: Add `style="display: none;"` to your `div`, then click the Send button and see if it displays.

Comment: Update your question with whatever you're working on now. Make sure to clearly delineate which file is which (separate the code blocks). Also, you should remove all the extra line breaks in whatever your mail.php file is for ease of readability.